# Example of inheritance on a database (logical data model)

Tags: database-design, inheritance

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database), there are a great answer about this question but i don't found clear examples about what's next, for example, queries (select).

I'm going to describe an example and I want to know if i do correctly so:

We have a base class about payments:

```
Payments( code_payment (PK), description )
```

And then, we have 3 sub-class (3 differents types of payments on inheritance ):

```
Cash( code_payment (FK) )
CreditCard( creditcard_account , code_payment(FK) )
PromissoryNote( pay_date , code_payment(FK) )
```

**For example:** for insert statements, **first**, insert on Payments table and **second**, depending of *type of payments* ( I think in code you use if/else clause to separate the types of payments and do the correct "insert statement"), insert where belongs. And what happens with select statements?

Imagine that i want to know what type of payment had a specific document assuming that I have a table called **Document** that it is connected with **Payments table** ( so Document table have a foreign key to Payments *(code_payment)* ).

First i should do is to get the **"description"** of the payments by making a query on Document and Payments table (basically an inner join) and then, **depending of the result** (cash, credic card or promissory note) make a query on the table that belongs.

Is this what I suppose to do? am I on the correct way? Maybe it can works but it looks like a little bit... you know.. no elegant solution. I am a little confuse about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd build one updatable view for each "subclass". Each view would join the "base class" table with the "subclass" table.

Application code uses the views, not the base tables.

Since payment types are exclusive--a single payment can't be both cash and credit card--you need to use overlapping constraints.

```
create table payments (
  code_payment integer not null, -- I hope this is some kind of payment identifier.
  payment_type char(2) not null
    check (payment_type in ('CA', 'CC', 'PN')),
  amount decimal(14, 2) not null check (amount > 0),
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'X',
  primary key (code_payment),
  unique (code_payment, payment_type)
);

create table cash_payments (
  code_payment integer not null,
  payment_type char(2) not null default 'CA'
    check (payment_type = 'CA'),
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'X',
  primary key (code_payment),
  unique (code_payment, payment_type),
  foreign key (code_payment, payment_type) 
    references payments (code_payment, payment_type) 
);
```

Tables for credit card payments and promissory note payments are similar.

The unique constraint on `payments (code_payment, payment_type)` lets those columns be the target for foreign key constraints. The check constraint and foreign key constraint in the table "cash_payments" guarantees that rows in "cash_payments" will always match a *cash* row in the payments table; they can never match any other kind of row.  The unique constraint in "cash_payments" lets the named columns be the target for further foreign key constraints, just like the unique constraint in "payments" does.

> Imagine that i want to know what type of payment had a specific document assuming that I have a table called Document that it is connected with Payments table ( so Document table have a foreign key to Payments *(code_payment)* ).

Documents can be related to payments with a foreign key referencing either

- the "code_payment" column, or
- the pair of columns "code_payment" and "payment_type".

If the "documents" table references the pair of columns, you know what the type of payment is, so you know which table(s) you need to join on.

Comment: I was thinking to classify types of payments in a new Table (TypesPayments for example that have two fields (code and name of payment), so, in your "payment_type" field on "payments" table would be an integer that it is a foreign key that references to primary key of the new TypesPayments). So, if I want to know what type of payment is, i have to make a query on Payments type, and second, another query on TypesPayments.

Comment: I wasn't using check constraint or views on my proyect. ( I'm  working with base table directly). But you changed my mind. Thank you it was really usefull for me. I have to learn yet.